# Ubuntu 20.04 IEC958/SPDIF/Optical audio no sound

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, configuration

I am new to Linux and am running Ubuntu 20.04. I am using MSI motherboard and do not hear any sound output while using Fiber Optic Audio cable.

I tried using:

```
sudo aplay -l
```

and got the following output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: ALC1220VBDT [ALC1220-VB-DT], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: ALC1220VBDT [ALC1220-VB-DT], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: ALC1220VBDT [ALC1220-VB-DT], device 2: USB Audio [USB Audio #2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: ALC1220VBDT [ALC1220-VB-DT], device 3: USB Audio [USB Audio #3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I think my audio card is being rcognized (ALC1220VBDT)

I also tried adjusting the setting on Sound settings, Alsamixer and Pulse Audio.

I see the sound being Output through the mixers but cant hear anything. I have tried reinstalling alsamixer and pulse audio but no success. I also tried using wired headphones and did not get any sound. Please let me know if I can provide any more information about my configuration. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you